# Variable de sesión en C# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Buen día, tengo una duda en este tema, tengo un formulario `MDIParent` en el cual se encuentra el **menu principal** de mi aplicación y así mismo en este formulario se muestran todas las vetanas que componen a dicho **menu**, la pregunta básicamente es la siguiente: **¿Como puedo pasar el nombre del usuario logueado a todos y cada uno de los otros formularios?** que componen la suite ya que *por medio del siguiente código*, **envió del form Login al form Menu el perfil del usuario para que le muestre o le oculte ciertos form del Menu.**

```
readonly frmMenu frmMain;
public frmLogin( frmMenu main)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    frmMain = main;
}
//envio un valor boleano al form menu    
frmMain.ObtenerValidacion(true, Perfil);
//recibo los valores del login y ocuto o muestro forms en base al      perfil del usuario
public void ObtenerValidacion(bool valido, int perfil)
{
}
```

**Lo que estoy haciendo es esto en el Login**

```
public void EnviarUsuario()
{
    try
    {
        if (User1!="")
        {                    
            objCatalogoArticulos.ObtenerUsuario(User1);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.ToString();
    }
}
```

**Donde User1 es el usuario registrado y validado en la BD** y *en el formulario de catálogo de articulos que es uno de los que componen la suite intento cachar al usuario logueado por medio de este metodo.*

```
public void ObtenerUsuario(string Usuario)
{
    try
    {
        UsuarioConectado = Usuario;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.ToString();
    }
}
```

*Y con este metodo pretendo a traves del metodo load del formulario de articulos mostrar al usuario logueado en un label* y el cual no surje efecto por que en alguna parte del codigo el usuario que si existe y esta logueado se pierde.

```
public void ReconocerUsuario()
{
    try
    {
        if (UsuarioConectado!="")
        {
            lblUsarioArt.Text = UsuarioConectado;
        }
        else
        {
            lblUsarioArt.Text = ".";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.ToString();
    }
}
```

Espero puedan ayudarme o darme sugerencias de como realizarlo.

Comment: No estas mostrando donde guardas el usuario.. en una clase? una variable?

Comment: El usuario esta en el login y lo envio por medio del metodo EnviarUsuario.

Comment: Entiendo que `UsuarioConectado` es una variable del formulario principal. Simplemente, haz esta variable publica y accede desde los formularios hijos con algo asi como `MDIParent.UsuarioConectado`.

Comment: En realidad ahora que lo pienso, deberías hacer un casting antes de poder acceder. `((frmMenu)MDIParent).UsuarioConectado;`